# What's the factor of $x^{40} $ in $(1+x^4+x^5)^{100}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying this problem but it gets complicated after a few steps, can someone add some feedback between them?

Additional information to the problem:

> Observe that equation $4i + 5j = 40$ has as integer solutions: $(i,j) \in \{ (0,8), (5,4), (10,0) \}$

Steps:

We know that: $$ (s+t)^n = \sum\limits_{r=0}^n {{n}\choose{r}} s^rt^{n-r}$$

For $s = x^5$ and $t = 1+x^4$:

$$(1 + x^4 + x^5)^{100} = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{100} {{100}\choose{r}} x^{5r} (1+x^4)^{100-r} \implies \bigstar $$

> This is supposed to be an intermediate step that uses again the first rule for analyzing $(1+x^4)^{100-r}$: 
>   $$(1+x^4)^{100-j} = \sum\limits_{\textbf{k=0}}^{\textbf{100-r}} {{100-r}\choose{k}} x^{4k}$$
>   I think there is a typo in the presentation and the correct one is:
>   $$(1+x^4)^{100-r} = \sum\limits_{\textbf{k=0}}^{\textbf{100-r}} {{100-r}\choose{k}} x^{4k}$$

Using the above we get to:
$$\bigstar \implies (1+x^4+x^5)^{100} = \sum\limits_{\textbf{r=0}}^{\textbf{100}} {{100}\choose{r}} x^{5r} \sum\limits_{\textbf{k=0}}^{\textbf{100-r}} {{100-r}\choose{k}} x^{4k}$$

In order to compute $x^{40}$'s factor we have to choose $k$ and $r$ so that $4k + 5r = 40$, with $k$ and $r$ positive integers less than 100. They are computed for us in the beginning, so the factor of $x^{40}$ is:

> $$ {{100}\choose{8}} {{92}\choose{0}} + {{100}\choose{4}}{{96}\choose{5}} + {{100}\choose{0}} {{100}\choose{10}}$$

**Question: How do we get the last step?** (I know that $C(n,r)$ is the formula to find the factor but this is a little bit more complicated (e.g. the sums have different counters) ).

Comment: Yes, that answer is exactly the right formula.

Comment: Seems like a double application of Newton's Binomium to me

Comment: $4i+5j=40$ has infinitely many solutions in integers unless restricted by $i$ and/or $j\ge0$

Comment: I don't question the answer, I'm asking for some in-depth analysis especially in the step where $j$ shows up from nowhere.
@lab bhattacharjee: i think they are ≥0 (they don't state it but I think it's an unspoken given from the hint at the start).

Comment: Of course, $k,r$ are not positive, but non-negative - they are allowed to be zero.

Comment: $k$ and $r$ are supposed to take $i$ and $j$, so they can be positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to understand what's going on here, I think, is to think about you're doing when you expand an expression like $(1+x^4+x^5)^{100}$:  You're taking the $100$-term product

$$(1+x^4+x^5)(1+x^4+x^5)\cdots(1+x^4+x^5)$$

and picking *one* term from each factor to multiply together, in all $3^{100}$ different ways of picking out one term per factor.  The coefficient of $x^{40}$ is just the number of ways you can do so to get a product with that power of $x$.  As you noted, there are three combinations of $4$s and $5$s that add up to $40$:  ten $4$s and no $5$s, eight $5$s and no $4$s, and five $4$ and four $5$s.  What this really means is that the three cases amount to picking

1) $x^4$ from $10$ of the factors, and $1$ from all the rest

2) $x^5$ from $8$ of the factors, and $1$ from all the rest

3) $x^4$ from $5$ of the factors, $x^5$ from $4$ *other* factors, and $1$ from all the rest

The first of these can be done in $100\choose10$ ways, the second in $100\choose8$ ways, and the third in ${100\choose5}{95\choose4}$ ways.  So the total number of ways of getting $x^{40}$ is the sum,

$${100\choose10}+{100\choose8}+{100\choose5}{95\choose4}$$

Finally, note that I probably should have looked back at the original posting before writing all this up, in which case I would have written the third case as picking the $4$ $x^5$s first, followed by the $5$ $x^4$s.  But the result is the same, since ${100\choose5}{95\choose4}={100\choose4}{96\choose5}={100!\over4!5!91!}$

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Using [Multinomial Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialSeries.html),  $$(1+x^4+x^5)^{100}=\sum_{a+b+c=100}\frac{100!}{a!b!c!}x^{4b+5c}$$ where $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers

Comment: This is another way but can you help without using the trinomial expansion? A liiiitle irrelevant but how does $\sum_{a+b+c=100}$ expand? If you have a link that expands it I would be grateful.... (one thought is that it uses only the solutions from the equation... but hey, that's just one thought....)

Comment: Why so many votes up.... this is not what this question is looking for, guys don't upvote just because it's an elegant solution....

Comment: @user2692669: but it is a good hint. You want to sum the terms where $4b+5c=40$. That is,
$$
(a,b,c)\in\{(90,10,0),(91,5,4),(92,0,8)\}
$$
so you have to add $3$ coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Use the trinomial expansion $$(1 + x^4 + x^5)^{100} = \sum_{i+j+k=100} {100 \choose i,j,k} x^{4j} x^{5k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To finish the problem using the method shown, you have to find the solutions in nonnegative integers to the equation $4k+5r=40$; and these are given to be $k=0, r=8$ and $k=5, r=4$ and $k=10, r=0$.
Substituting these values into the expression $\binom{100}{r} \binom{100-r}{k}$ and adding the results gives the answer they got.

Comment: How do we get the last expression? (the adding part for different solutions I understand because it's **one** of the three, but the multiplication...? Can someone explain/expand how we get there?)

Comment: From the starred equation, this expression gives the coefficient of $x^{5r+4k}$, and we want to use the values of r and k that make this exponent equal 40.

Comment: But they have different counters: first has from $0$ to $100$ second has from $0$ to $100-r$

Comment: You're right, but we're guaranteed that $0\le k$ and $k\le 100-r$ since we're using nonnegative values of k and $k+r\le 5r+4k=40\le 100$.